# Accessing Feed (posts) of an Unpublished Page via the Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Is there a way to access the *Feed* of an *Unpublished Page* in Facebook via the Graph API?

The command used is: `https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/feed?access_token=`

When I try, no data is retrieved (empty Data returned). If I publish the page, I can access the feed and retrieve the posts without a problem. I'm using a *Page Access Token* which was retrieved using the *User Access Token* of the page's admin (with the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions). I've tried using the admin's *User Access Token* as well, but no luck.

Retrieving page metadata, posting to the page as well as fetching Page Conversations work without a problem whether the page is published or unpublished.

I want to keep the page in an unpublished state while we are testing. Please assist.

Comment: _“I'm using a Page Access Token which has the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions of the Administrator of the page.”_ – a _page_ access token can not have manage_pages and publish_stream permissions, only user access tokens can. Just use a user access token of an admin that can access the unpublished page.

Comment: @CBroe the page access token was retrieved using the user access token (of the admin) which has the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions. I've tried to use the admin's user access token as well, but I still get no data returned if the page is unpublished. I've found no details on the Facebook developer site regarding accessing feeds of unpublished pages via the api and I'm therefor not sure if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant the `read_stream` permission to the application that was used to obtain the page access token.